# yii2 or jQuery listbox with filter

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, listbox, yii2

I'm looking for a solution for a single listbox, similar to [bootstrap double listbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) with a filter on the top. I would like to sort some items which are listed in the first listbox and I need to put them to other 4 categories / listboxes. The solution should be able to move items between the main listbox and the 4 categories vice versa.

Long story short, I would like to create a bootstrap listbox with a filter on the top which can move elements between not just 2 but among 4 other listboxses.

Can anyone suggest me an approach?

Comment: seems you are looking for select2 extension ...https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2    sample and demo http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanks for your prompt response! I know select2 but can it be configured to behave like a listbox and not a drop-down?

Comment: http://labs.easyblog.it/bootstrap-list-filter/

Comment: @makshh Thanks! I'll give it a try and post my findings soon.

Comment: @makshh It seems bootstrap-list-filter doesn't support multiple selection after filtering. And I think this is true for select2 as well.